# Dell P2014H displaying jagged black lines. 1600x900, 60Hz. Display port

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure

Connected to Dell U2715H 2560x1440, 60Hz via display port cable.  Worked fine last night.  Displaying strange black, jagged lines across display.  Panel menu functions seem unaffected and display normally.  Have tried updating graphics drivers, unplugging/plugging, and adjusting resolution settings.  The affected part of the display seems stretched with the black lines not breaking up the desktop. Windows 10, nvidia [image: The Issue.]
[image: Menu unaffected.]

Comment: Tried another cable/different input?

Comment: That does correct the issue, but it would be my preference to daisychain the displayport to cut down on cables.

Comment: if you're daisy chaining it, try it with another cable still, if it *still* fails, the issue might be in the *other* monitor. Else its the cable. if they're both the same type of DP try swapping them around to see what happens with different combinations of cables and screens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments

I suspect its the cable - swapping the cable seems to have fixed the issue, though the OP wants to daisy chain the monitors.

If the problem persists with another cable while daisychaining, the issue might be with the *primary* screen, and something could have failed there.